# JQuery UI Widget Programming

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hi, i'm creating chat ui with JQueryUI.

here some code:

```
$.widget("ui.chatwindow", {
    options: {
        nickname: "obama";
    },
    setNickname: function(nick){
        var self = this;
        var id_pre = 'wchat_' + self.options.nickname;
        $('#' + id_pre + '\\:name').text(self.options.nickname);
    },
    setStatus: function(status){
            var self = this;
            var id_pre = 'wchat_' + self.options.nickname;
            switch(status){
                case 1:
                    $('#' + id_pre + '\\:status').removeAttr('class');
                    $('#' + id_pre + '\\:status').addClass('chat-icon-online');
                    $('#' + id_pre + '\\:status').attr('title','Online');
                    break;
                    ...
                default:
                    break;                    
            }
            ...
        },
    ...
}
```

My Question is i always write in every method:

```
var self = this;
var id_pre = 'wchat_' + self.options.nickname;
```

to change element class or text content 
is this a good or efficient way to code? 
let me know the good and efficient way to do this.

thanks for your kind.

Comment: This is a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Your two `var` statements will probably be cheaper than doing `$('#' + id_pre + '\\:status')` three times in a row.

Comment: I'm curious to know, what is gained by assigning this to self?

Comment: @mu-is-too-short use `var = $(selection)` may be can be cheaper, but how to reduce the repetition in call from many method?

Comment: @stefgosselin I just found `var self = this`,  in jquery-ui custom. Don't know the purpose :). 
I found many.

Comment: @stefgosselin: The `var self = this;` idiom is used when you need to refer to `this` inside a callback; remember that `this` is a keyword, not a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would be better on the code review site but I started something in the comments so I guess I should finish it.

First of all, if you're going to keep saying this:

```
var id_pre = 'wchat_' + self.options.nickname;
```

over and over again, you should do it just once in your `_create` function:

```
_create: function() {
    this.id_pre = 'wchat_' + this.options.nickname;
    //...
}
```

Then you can just refer to `this.id_pre` when you need it. You can do similar things with `$('#' + id_pre + '\\:status')`:

```
_create: function() {
    this.id_pre  = 'wchat_' + this.options.nickname;
    this.$id_pre = $('#' + id_pre + '\\:status');
    //...
}
```

But keep in mind that caching jQuery objects like this can cause odd results if you're adding and remove elements that you've wrapped in `$()`.

You only need to do this:

```
var self = this;
```

when you want to refer to the outer `this` inside a callback. This simple variable is pretty cheap so I wouldn't worry about it but you should know why the idiom exists and when you need it.